# Multiple webservers (NGINX) behind Load Balancer, share settings (database connections etc.)

Tags: php, nginx, load-balancing

I'm designing a system that will require several web servers (NGINX) behind a load balancer.

My question is: what techniques do you suggest using for sharing settings among all webbservers (hosting a PHP-app)? Let's say that I have to change the credentials for the database connection. In that case I don't want to log in to every single server and change all of the config files.

What do you suggest I do to be able to update those variables in one place so it's accessible for all web servers. I've considered having a small server in the middle which all servers read from (through a scp-connection or such), but I don't want a single point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

There are various solutions to automate server management like Puppet and Chef, but if you are just getting started with two our three servers, consider a tool that's like you send broadcast the same SSH session to multiple hosts. [Terminator for Gnome](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2012/10/16/how-to-send-input-to-many-terminals/) is great and there's also [CSSHX for mac](https://www.outsideopen.com/csshx/) (which I haven't tried).

It's great to be able to see both terminals at once in case there are small differences between the server from prior manual maintenance. In Terminator, you can easily switch between broadcasting your commands to a group of terminals and typing into a specific one. You can set up a layout that automatically starts up two joined sessions and SSH's into all the servers in a given cluster. In other words, it's as easy to use as a SSH session normally would be, but works for multiple servers.

When project size and complexity grows, consider switching to more fully automated server management.